# Is it possible to send NSString to server without using key value pair iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlrequest

I have tried using `NSURLRequest` to send NSString to server without using key-value pair but got the response as null value. Can anyone please provide information regarding this?
Thank you in advance...

code which I have tried:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:someUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",someString];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[someUrl host]];
NSError *error=nil;

// generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
NSLog(@" json %@  ",json);
```

Comment: The Response doesn't depends on only IOS side, you should check the backEnd as well . How do you handle this Url call with the parameter..

Comment: am also expecting answer for this